# How to insert text at cursor position using insertText in summernote Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, summernote

I'm using Angular 8.
I'm using text editor summernote.
In summernote I have to insert text at particular cursor position,I have seen in https://summernote.org/deep-dive/ summernote documentation, but how to insert text from API to insert at particular cursor position.
Here is my stackbiltz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-summernote-demo-xznhjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts